# pcs cluster not moving resource when instructed to move

Tags: resources, pacemaker, pcs

for whatever reason I'm no more able to move resources with `pcs`

```
pacemaker-1.1.16-12.el7_4.8.x86_64
corosync-2.4.0-9.el7_4.2.x86_64
pcs-0.9.158-6.el7.centos.1.x86_64
Linux server_a.test.local 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
```

I have 4 resources configured as part of resource group. Here's the log from the action when I tried to move the `ClusterIP` resource from `server_d` to `server_a` using `pcs resource move ClusterIP servr_a.test.local`

```
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Forwarding cib_delete operation for section constraints to all (origin=local/crm_resource/3)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       Diff: --- 0.24.0 2
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       Diff: +++ 0.25.0 (null)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       -- /cib/configuration/constraints/rsc_location[@id='cli-prefer-ClusterIP']
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       +  /cib:  @epoch=25
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:       Transition aborted by deletion of rsc_location[@id='cli-prefer-ClusterIP']: Configuration change | cib=0.25.0 source=te_update_diff:456 path=/cib/configuration/constraints/rsc_location[@id='cli-prefer-ClusterIP'] complete=true
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:  State transition S_IDLE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE | input=I_PE_CALC cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=abort_transition_graph
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_delete operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=server_d.test.local/crm_resource/3, version=0.25.0)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: determine_online_status:      Node server_a.test.local is online
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: determine_online_status:      Node server_d.test.local is online
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 1 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 2 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 1 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 2 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: group_print:   Resource Group: my_app
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      Apache     (systemd:httpd):        Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      stunnel    (systemd:stunnel-my_app): Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      my_app-daemon        (systemd:my_app): Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   ClusterIP       (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   Apache  (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   stunnel (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   my_app-daemon     (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:   notice: process_pe_message:   Calculated transition 8, saving inputs in /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-18.bz2
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Forwarding cib_modify operation for section constraints to all (origin=local/crm_resource/4)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       Diff: --- 0.25.0 2
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       Diff: +++ 0.26.0 (null)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       +  /cib:  @epoch=26
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_perform_op:       ++ /cib/configuration/constraints:  <rsc_location id="cli-prefer-ClusterIP" rsc="ClusterIP" role="Started" node="server_a.test.local" score="INFINITY"/>
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_process_request:  Completed cib_modify operation for section constraints: OK (rc=0, origin=server_d.test.local/crm_resource/4, version=0.26.0)
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: abort_transition_graph:       Transition aborted by rsc_location.cli-prefer-ClusterIP 'create': Configuration change | cib=0.26.0 source=te_update_diff:456 path=/cib/configuration/constraints complete=true
Apr 06 12:16:26 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: handle_response:      pe_calc calculation pe_calc-dc-1523016986-67 is obsolete
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: determine_online_status:      Node server_a.test.local is online
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: determine_online_status:      Node server_d.test.local is online
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 1 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 2 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 1 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: unpack_node_loop:     Node 2 is already processed
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: group_print:   Resource Group: my_app
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      Apache     (systemd:httpd):        Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      stunnel    (systemd:stunnel-my_app): Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: common_print:      my_app-daemon        (systemd:my_app): Started server_d.test.local
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   ClusterIP       (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   Apache  (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   stunnel (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:     info: LogActions:   Leave   my_app-daemon     (Started server_d.test.local)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17291] server_d.test.local    pengine:   notice: process_pe_message:   Calculated transition 9, saving inputs in /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-19.bz2
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: do_state_transition:  State transition S_POLICY_ENGINE -> S_TRANSITION_ENGINE | input=I_PE_SUCCESS cause=C_IPC_MESSAGE origin=handle_response
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: do_te_invoke: Processing graph 9 (ref=pe_calc-dc-1523016987-68) derived from /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-19.bz2
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:   notice: run_graph:    Transition 9 (Complete=0, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=0, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-19.bz2): Complete
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:     info: do_log:       Input I_TE_SUCCESS received in state S_TRANSITION_ENGINE from notify_crmd
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17292] server_d.test.local       crmd:   notice: do_state_transition:  State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_IDLE | input=I_TE_SUCCESS cause=C_FSA_INTERNAL origin=notify_crmd
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_backup:      Archived previous version as /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib-34.raw
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:   Wrote version 0.25.0 of the CIB to disk (digest: 7511cba55b6c2f2f481a51d5585b8d36)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:   Reading cluster configuration file /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.tPIv7m (digest: /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.OwHiKz)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_backup:      Archived previous version as /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib-35.raw
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:   Wrote version 0.26.0 of the CIB to disk (digest: 7f962ed676a49e84410eee2ee04bae8c)
Apr 06 12:16:27 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_file_write_with_digest:   Reading cluster configuration file /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.MnRP4u (digest: /var/lib/pacemaker/cib/cib.B5sWNH)
Apr 06 12:16:31 [17287] server_d.test.local        cib:     info: cib_process_ping:     Reporting our current digest to server_d.test.local: 8182592cb4922cbf007158ab0a277190 for 0.26.0 (0x5575234afde0 0)
```

Important to notethat if I execute `pcs cluster stop server_b.test.local` all resources inside the configure group are moved to the other node.

What's going on? Like I said it worked and no changes have been made since then.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
pcs config

[root@server_a ~]# pcs config
Cluster Name: my_app_cluster
Corosync Nodes:
 server_a.test.local server_d.test.local
Pacemaker Nodes:
 server_a.test.local server_d.test.local

Resources:
 Group: my_app
  Resource: ClusterIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
   Attributes: cidr_netmask=24 ip=10.116.63.49
   Operations: monitor interval=10s timeout=20s (ClusterIP-monitor-interval-10s)
               start interval=0s timeout=20s (ClusterIP-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=20s (ClusterIP-stop-interval-0s)
  Resource: Apache (class=systemd type=httpd)
   Operations: monitor interval=60 timeout=100 (Apache-monitor-interval-60)
               start interval=0s timeout=100 (Apache-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=100 (Apache-stop-interval-0s)
  Resource: stunnel (class=systemd type=stunnel-my_app)
   Operations: monitor interval=60 timeout=100 (stunnel-monitor-interval-60)
               start interval=0s timeout=100 (stunnel-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=100 (stunnel-stop-interval-0s)
  Resource: my_app-daemon (class=systemd type=my_app)
   Operations: monitor interval=60 timeout=100 (my_app-daemon-monitor-interval-60)
               start interval=0s timeout=100 (my_app-daemon-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=100 (my_app-daemon-stop-interval-0s)

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
  Resource: Apache
    Enabled on: server_d.test.local (score:INFINITY) (role: Started) (id:cli-prefer-Apache)
  Resource: ClusterIP
    Enabled on: server_a.test.local (score:INFINITY) (role: Started) (id:cli-prefer-ClusterIP)
  Resource: my_app-daemon
    Enabled on: server_a.test.local (score:INFINITY) (role: Started) (id:cli-prefer-my_app-daemon)
  Resource: stunnel
    Enabled on: server_a.test.local (score:INFINITY) (role: Started) (id:cli-prefer-stunnel)
Ordering Constraints:
Colocation Constraints:
Ticket Constraints:

Alerts:
 No alerts defined

Resources Defaults:
 No defaults set
Operations Defaults:
 No defaults set

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: my_app_cluster
 dc-version: 1.1.16-12.el7_4.8-94ff4df
 have-watchdog: false
 stonith-enabled: false

Quorum:
  Options:
```

**EDIT2**

When I run `crm_simulate -sL` I get the following output:

```
[root@server_a ~]# crm_simulate -sL

    Current cluster status:
    Online: [ server_a.test.local server_d.test.local ]

     Resource Group: my_app
         ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server_a.test.local
         Apache     (systemd:httpd):        Started server_a.test.local
         stunnel    (systemd:stunnel-my_app): Started server_a.test.local
         my_app-daemon        (systemd:my_app): Started server_a.test.local

    Allocation scores:
    group_color: my_app allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
    group_color: my_app allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
    group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
    group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: INFINITY
    group_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
    group_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: INFINITY
    group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
    group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
    native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: INFINITY
    native_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    native_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY
    native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY
    native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: INFINITY
    native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY

    Transition Summary:
```

Next I deleted all resources and added them back (again as before - I have it documented) and when running the command `crm_simulate -sL` I get now different results:

```
[root@server_a ~]# crm_simulate -sL

Current cluster status:
Online: [ server_a.test.local server_d.test.local ]

 Resource Group: my_app
     ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server_a.test.local
     Apache     (systemd:httpd):        Started server_a.test.local
     stunnel    (systemd:stunnel-my_app.service): Started server_a.test.local
     my_app-daemon        (systemd:my_app.service): Started server_a.test.local

Allocation scores:
group_color: my_app allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
native_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
native_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY
native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY
native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: -INFINITY
```

And I'm able to move resources but when I do and run the `crm_simulate -sL` command again it get a different output than before!

```
[root@server_a ~]# crm_simulate -sL

Current cluster status:
Online: [ server_a.test.local server_d.test.local ]

 Resource Group: my_app
     ClusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server_d.test.local
     Apache     (systemd:httpd):        Started server_d.test.local
     stunnel    (systemd:stunnel-my_app.service): Started server_d.test.local
     my_app-daemon        (systemd:my_app.service): Started server_d.test.local

Allocation scores:
group_color: my_app allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: INFINITY
group_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
group_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_a.test.local: 0
native_color: ClusterIP allocation score on server_d.test.local: INFINITY
native_color: Apache allocation score on server_a.test.local: -INFINITY
native_color: Apache allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_a.test.local: -INFINITY
native_color: stunnel allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0
native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_a.test.local: -INFINITY
native_color: my_app-daemon allocation score on server_d.test.local: 0

Transition Summary:
```

I'm kinda confused :/ Is it an expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

not sure I got your last answer right but I took a closer look at `man pcs` and found this:

> move  [destination node] [--master] [lifetime=]
>   [--wait[=n]]
>                 Move  the resource off the node it is currently running on by creating a -INFINITY location constraint to ban the node.  If
>   destination node is specified the resource will be moved to that node
>   by creating an INFINITY
>                 location constraint to prefer the destination node.  If --master is used the scope of the command is limited to the master role and you must use the master id (instead of the resource id).  If 
>   lifetime  is  specified
>                 then  the  constraint  will  expire after that time, otherwise it defaults to infinity and the constraint can be cleared
>   manually with 'pcs resource clear' or 'pcs constraint delete'.  If
>   --wait is specified, pcs will
>                 wait up to 'n' seconds for the resource to move and then return 0 on success or 1 on error.  If 'n' is not specified it
>   defaults to 60 minutes.  If you want the resource to preferably avoid
>   running on some  nodes  but
>                 be able to failover to them use 'pcs location avoids'.

Using  `pcs resource clear` cleared the constraint and I could move the resources.

Answer (score 1):

The `score:INFINITY` preference constraints on all your grouped resources are likely the issue. `INFINITY` is actually equal to `1,000,000` in Pacemaker, which is the highest value that can be assigned to a score.

The following is true when working with `INFINITY` (from the ClusterLabs documentation):

> ```
> 6.1.1. Infinity Math 
>   Pacemaker implements INFINITY (or equivalently, +INFINITY) 
>   internally as a score of 1,000,000. Addition and subtraction 
>   with it follow these three basic rules: 
>
>   Any value + INFINITY =  INFINITY 
>   Any value - INFINITY = -INFINITY 
>   INFINITY  - INFINITY = -INFINITY
> ```

Try changing your preference scores to something like `1,000`, or `10,000` rather than `INFINITY`, and run your test again.

Comment: Matt, please see the EDIT2 in my question.

Comment: @yesOrMaybeWhatever: Are you unmoving the resources after you move them? Moving the resources places location constraints into the cluster to make the resources move. You need to `unmove` them to remove those constraints after the resources have moved if you expect them to be able to failover/failback to the peer.

Comment: Hello Matt, please apologize for replaying so late (had a nasty infection). Are you referring to commands in the `Move resources` section [move resource](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/doc/pcs-crmsh-quick-ref.md#move-resources) If yes, then how do I need to run the resource and on which node ? I mean, because all 4 resources are in a group I tell for example to move the ClusterIP but of course it then moves all 4 resources. Do I then need to run  pcs resource clear for each of the 4 resources on the host that got the resources assigned due to the move operation ? Thanks!

Comment: The four nodes in your group appear to have preference scores of `INFINITY`; those need to be removed, or something lower. `pcs constraint remove cli-prefer-Apache cli-prefer-ClusterIP cli-prefer-my_app-daemon cli-prefer-stunnel`. Then you should be able to `move` your resources.